# Improving Ad-Hoc Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2012

Details:
SQL Server 2012.
Multi-Tenant DB Architecture.

I am having a problem with user generate ad-hoc reporting queries jamming up my SQL box.

A typical report may include 7 tables, (ranging from 10k rows to over 500k
rows), 5 WHERE clauses and 2 sorting filters. These queries, as you can
imagine, are quite expensive and can take minutes. The problem is
these queries will max out SQL CPU and can take up over 20GB of tempdb
space. Thus causing every other app that uses the database to timeout.

Since these are user generated reports, I can't really tune the queries for performance. At over 2000 clients and rising, giving each client its own set of views or schemas is out of the question.

My question is how can I tune my database for ad-hoc queries or somehow limit a query so it doesn't take up all of the server resources? As of right now, if someone runs a big report, the entire server hangs until I reset SQL Service. Obviously this is not sustainable.

Is there a best practice out there for expensive query multi-tenant
databases?

EDIT:

I have a query that can replicate the problem, however if I run it on my local development server the tempDB grows the same, but the process doesn't eat up CPU like it does on my AWS instance. (3% cpu on local vs 58% on EC2 m3.large).

Local CPU- Intel Xeon E3-1230 V2

EC2 CPU- Intel Xeon E5-2670 V2

From what I can see, all of the server settings are pretty much identical.

Comment: Is [Optimize For Ad Hoc Workloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645587.aspx) enabled?  This may help if there is existing memory pressure.

Comment: @DMason helps nothing. Only changes the way query plans are cached.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the ironclad fix for your problem... But, your plan cache *may* be bloated with execution plans that never get reused.  Enabling Optimize For Ad Hoc Workloads helps mitigate that, freeing up space in the buffer pool.  I would not categorize that as "helps nothing".

Comment: You may need to get extreme and create a copy (replicated) read only for ad-hoc.  And lots of indexes.

Comment: @DMason thanks for the suggestion. It wasn't turned on, but I'm not sure it will help much. After resetting SQL Server, the very first query will hang and clog everything up, so I don't think it's a memory problem. The server has 7.5GB of RAM and sits at around 87% utilization.

Comment: If there's a specific report query that is causing some pain, maybe post the query and an execution plan...

Comment: Another thought: does the report query go parallel?  Have you tried the MAXDOP query hint for the report query?  ie `SELECT * FROM TABLE OPTION (MAXDOP X)`...you could set X as ½ or ¼ the number of logical CPUs.

Comment: Not a production fix but run the query on both with (nolock) to see if locks are the difference.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similiar problem in my company. We used a multi pronged solution to control ad hoc runaway queries. It may/may not be useful to you. In brief our design was:

- We used resource governor to define Pools and workgroups. All
  application connections/UI/Downstream queries were classified into ,
  lets say, group 1/pool 1.
- All user connections were classified to group 2/pool 2
- Only Group 2/Pool 2 was restricted to access only 20% of the CPU resources. Please mind that this will be invoked and applied only on new connections post server stress. This means when server is overloaded, then all new connectrions qualifying for pool 2 will be restricted.
- We also needed to kill any runaway queries if server is under stress. So we raised a window'e event in case pool 2 queries ran for more than 10 minutes. The windows service will get info about the runaway queries and insert data into a housekeeping table.
- A SQL agent would run every 10 minutes and look for queries inserted in the housekeeping table and kill those queries.

This is a comprehensive solution which you can customize and deploy as needed.